# webrtc datachannel sctp details

Tags: webrtc, sctp, rtcdatachannel

When a webrtc datachannel is connected, I'd like to get details about the connection.  (I admit I'm still fuzzy about ice and renegotiation).

In my datachannel.onopen I tried to get sctp

```
var sctp = myPeerConnection.sctp;
```

but it is returning undefined.  Is it just not implemented yet in Chrome and Firefox?  How can I see the actual transport used since localDescription and remoteDescription both have all the ice candidates but not the final chosen transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/sctp

> The read-only sctp property on the RTCPeerConnection interface returns an RTCSctpTransport describing the SCTP transport over which SCTP data is being sent and received. If SCTP hasn't been negotiated, this value is **null**.

So it's seems that your datachannel is not using SCTP.
If you are using Chrome, you can have more details about your webrtc session using this address : chrome://webrtc-internals/

EDIT : returning undefined is not the same as null, sorry for the mistake. The documentation says that this feature is not (yet?) supported by Chrome and Firefox...

To see more info about your datachannel session, you can also use wireshark.